# Array returns 3-dimensional array instead of two. PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I'm having a problem with a **two-dimensional array** in the system I'm currently working with,
so here's my problem.
I'm using **Laravel** (if that's relevant information) and I have a controller called
**StationController** for a model called **Station**. Every **Station** has many **Booth**, and every **Booth** has many **Personnel**.
My problem is how could I return the query result to the view without using **JavaScript** or **Ajax**.

This is the structure for the view:

```
Station id: 1
 - Booth id: 1
   - Personnel id: 1
   - Personnel id: 2
   - Personnel id: 3
 - Booth id : 2
   - Personnel id: 4
   - Personnel id: 5
   - Personnel id: 6
Station id : 2
 ...
```

This is my function inside that controller, however it returns three-dimensional array instead of 2.

```
public function show($id){
    $stations = stations::getstationWhere($id); // select current station
    $station = $stations[0]; // select fields of the current station.
    $services = stationsServices::getstationsServicesWhere($id); // services of the current station.
    $service_booth = ServiceBooths::getServiceBoothBystation($id);

    foreach($service_booth as $key => $value){
        $booth_personnel[$key][$value->name] = BoothPersonnel::getBoothPersonnel($value->id);
    }



    return $booth_personnel;
}
```

Here's a screenshot of what it returns.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your relations on the models are set up correctly, you could do this:

```
Station::with('booth.personnel')->where('id', $id);
```

Now the 'booth' and 'personnel' needs to be the same name as the relation methods on your models. So it might be `Station::with('booths.personnel')`, depending on your naming conventions.